# docker.exe - This application could not be started

Tags: windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Installing `Docker Desktop` version 3.1.0 on `Windows 10` with `WSL 2`.

On first time running command `docker --version` it returns

```
docker.exe - This application could not be started
```

and a pop-up

[image]

which leads me to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/application-not-started?version=(null)&processName=docker.exe&platform=0009&osver=7&isServer=0&shimver=4.0.30319.0

I checked my .Net Version its fine and up to date.

And Next time I try to run `docker` command it returns

```
Program 'docker.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1
+ docker ps
+ ~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ docker ps
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

So this might be the issue of Permission, I couldn't agree more.

So I added my current Authenticated User in `docker-users` In-fact I added almost all the possible users in `docker-users`.

Still no luck

Then I gave Read Write permissions also, to all possible users.
But still no luck.

One very clear Solution, Re Install the `Windows` which I want to use as Last resource.

Jump in the dark will be appreciable

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, did you have any luck with this in the end? I have exactly the same issue!

Comment: @ChrisPont My system's antivirus and some Office policies were not allowing docker to run on WSL2

IT people relaxed the Policies and couple of restarts helped me in this s